# read values in a table with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, servlets

i have three columns in a html table whose rows r filled from json array values

```
 $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                      if(responseJson!=null){
                                            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");                                
                                            rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['attr']);                                
                                            rowNew.children().eq(1).html(value['ranking']);                                           
                                            rowNew.children().eq(2).html(value['type']);                                
                                            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                                        }
                                    });
```

Col1,col2,col3

a,drop1,drop2

b,drop3,drop4

column 3 and 4 are dropdown menus. when i select dropdown values for all the rows and submit it . i need to get the values in servlet something like this.
a - 1- int

b - 2 - string

how do i do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<table>` is inside a `<form>`, if you give the form elements a `name` attribute, you can get their value in servlet like

`request.getParameter("name-of-form-element");` as a string,

for eg

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

which you can cast into different types.